# Why use Release in TFS Iteration tree

Tags: tfs, scrum

We are doing a lot of maintenance work for previous versions of the product that we are developing and it feels stupid to have the release in the iteration path. Even if we wouldn't do any maintenance work, it feels unnecessary to have the  release in the iteration path so can someone explain me the reason why it is there by default? Is there a caveat on removing the release level from the tree?

What I would suggest is to have it like this? Does this make sense? We would only have sprints after another and the release is not related to them.

- Root

  - Sprint 1
  - Sprint 2
  - ...

How would you structure the iteration tree in a project where you do a lot of maintenance work for previous versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't wish to use a Release layer in your Iteration hierarchy you're free to remove it, and everything will still work fine.

Most teams don't release every Sprint, so in practice several sprints make up a single release, and people like to track this information using the Iteration Hierarchy.  They can then use it for reporting, to do things like "show me all PBI's included in Release 3".

Comment: Does the iteration really tell you that? It is only a period of time when the thing has been made. Not "to which release" it has been made to? In practice you could do new things for multiple releases but you only have one iteration ongoing at a time?

Comment: Most teams do group Sprints into specific releases.  If your team doesn't do this, then feel free to change the Iteration Hierarchy to reflect how you actually work.

Comment: Yeah, it works well if you don't do development for multiple releases during one sprint but for us it just doesn't make sense to include th release in the iteration path.